# Is this a good chart resizing method to tangle with D3.js and Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I am waiting to be brainstormed. In the search of a decent yet simple way to make a D3.js chart resizable inside a Bootstrap panel, after failed attempts using existing answers from the web, I did this. (Please refer my simple codes in the following and the charting code per se was adopted from [Bostock's example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245)). Since the chart is embedded inside a Bootstrap panel body, I first set the width and height attributes in the svg tag together with a viewBox setting. Then, in the charting script, I further removed the width and height attributes after reading them out. The result is a resizable chart upon window resizing. And the side effect is  warning on the console, saying "Unexpected value  parsing width/height attribute."

This trick avoids writing another script calling the windows.resize function. However, I also didn't figure out how to determine the size of the parent tag, in this case, the Boostrap panel body.

I am wondering if this is a reasonable trick. Although it works, I am eager to know if there are hidden traps I am unaware of. I am aware that some will find this trick naive.

Simple outline of the codes:

```
<div class="panel-body" id="contentPanel">
            <svg class="mainChart" width="800" height="500" viewBox="0 0 800 500" perserveAspectRatio="none"></svg>
        <script>
            var mainChart = d3.select(".mainChart");
            *[...codes on setting margins etc...]*
            //Trial trick: destroy the width and height attributes after using them. Then with viewBox, the chart is becoming responsive.
            mainChart.attr("width", "")
                     .attr("height", "");
            [...rest of charting codes...]
        </script>
</div>
```

Just to clarify, I understand this can be achieved by only setting viewBox and preserveAspectRatio. But still I like know if this has any advantage or disadvantage over directly writing a script to call window resize function.